# Can't create/update resources

Tags: services

I can't create/update nodes, taxonomy, users, etc., with Drupal Services. I can log in, retrieve system connection info and log out. Also, I can retrieve a node, user (all details), taxonomy term, index, etc. I have read a lot of internet pages like [this](https://gist.github.com/kylebrowning/affc9864487bb1b9c918), and [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120580/how-to-create-taxonomy-term-using-services), but It doesn't work for me. I have used firefox httprequester, firefox restclient, but nothing changed.

Thouse are the problems I have:

- If I send a GET to **http:< my path >/node**  I get all nodes in `json` format. Good.
- If I send a GET to **http:< my_path >/node/23**  I get Status 200 Ok but "[false]" returned. The same with .../23.json. But it I put the same url on a browser I get the node in json format.
- If I send a GET to **http:< my_path >/node?parameters[nid]=23** Then, I get the full json node.
- If I send a POST to **http:< my_path >/node** with `X-CSRF-token` and with the `json` right data to create a page, I always get 404 error: could not find the controller.
- If I send a PUT to **http:< my_path >/node/23** with `X-CSRF-token` and with the body data to node[title]=Prueba, I get 401 unauthorized: Missing required argument entity (but I'm logued in as admin as system/connec.json said).

I have checked all items when I configured the resources page of the service configuration. I'm using Drupal Commerce Kickstart installation.

What could I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search and test I have discovered where was the problem. If I enable [Universally Unique ID](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) module, I can't create/update entities. If I disable this module, all works good again. So the problem is with this module.

There is another open question about this issue in this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86574/put-or-post-not-working-with-services-uuid). So I think I should close this. Thanks.